# Вывод в ячейку Excel даты в формате dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss

Tags: excel, vba

Когда я пытаюсь вывести дату в Excel в формате `dd/mm/yyyy hh`, у меня это получается, дата выглядит, как и предполагалось:

> 20/10/2016 17
>
> 20/10/2016 18

В случае выше я вывожу дату и время следующим образом:

```
nRowDate = 1
For nDay = 20 To 21
    For nHour = 0 To 23
                If (nDay < 10) Then
                    Str = "0" + CStr(nDay) + "/" + MonthNumber + "/" + Year + " "
                Else
                    Str = CStr(nDay) + "/" + MonthNumber + "/" + Year + " "
                End If
                
                If (nHour < 10) Then
                    Str = Str + "0" + CStr(nHour)
                Else
                    Str = Str + CStr(nHour)
                End If
                
                Date_Array(nRowDate) = Str
                nRowDate = nRowDate + 1
                Cells(nRowDate, 1).Value = Format(Str, "dd/mm/yyyy hh")
          
    Next nHour
Next nDay
```

Но вывести дату в формате `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss` у меня не получается, вывод выглядит следующим образом:

> 20.10.2016 00:00:00
>
> 20.10.2016 00:00:10

Вот код:

```
nRowDate = 1
For nDay = 20 To 21
    For nHour = 0 To 23
        For nMinutes = 0 To 60
            For nSec = 0 To 5
                If (nDay < 10) Then
                    Str = "0" + CStr(nDay) + "/" + MonthNumber + "/" + Year + " "
                Else
                    Str = CStr(nDay) + "/" + MonthNumber + "/" + Year + " "
                End If
                
                If (nHour < 10) Then
                    Str = Str + "0" + CStr(nHour)
                Else
                    Str = Str + CStr(nHour)
                End If
                
                If (nMinutes < 10) Then
                    Str = Str + ":0" + CStr(nMinutes)
                Else
                   Str = Str + ":" + CStr(nMinutes)
                End If
                
                If (nSec = 0) Then
                    Str = Str + ":00"
                Else
                    Str = Str + ":0" + CStr(nSec * 10)
                End If
            
                Date_Array(nRowDate) = Str
                nRowDate = nRowDate + 1
                Cells(nRowDate, 1).Value = Format(Str, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
        
            Next nSec
        Next nMinutes
    Next nHour
Next nDay
```

Где я ошиблась?..

Comment: Везде.. Дату надо присваивать с типом Date, а не String. А форму вывода менять через формат ячеек, а не через форматирование строки.

Comment: @Qwertiy, спасибо за комментарий! А можете написать в ответ пример?

Comment: Опишите, пожалуйста, зачем такая вложенность циклов? Что Вы хотите получить?

Comment: @vikttur, вроде ж очевидно - дни, часы, минуты, секунды. Что не так с вложенностью?

Comment: Я о самой задаче. Забудем о VBA на время )  Основная задача в чем?

Comment: @vikttur, мне нужно вывести время в формате dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss с периодичностью каждые 10 секунд (20/10/2016 00:00:00, 20/10/2016 00:00:10 и т.д.)

Comment: Теперь понятно. Приходите позже )

Comment: @vikttur, а до этого было непонятно?))

Comment: До этого лень было код читать ) Добавил в ответ свой вариант

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Дату надо присваивать с типом Date, а не String.
2. Формат вывода менять через формат ячеек, а не через форматирование строки.

Можно сделать как-то так:

```
Sub Fill()
    Dim D As Integer, H As Integer, M As Integer, S As Integer
    Dim I As Integer

    I = 0
    For D = 20 To 21
        For H = 0 To 23
            For M = 0 To 59
                For S = 0 To 50 Step 10
                    I = I + 1
                    With ActiveSheet.Cells(I, 1)
                        .Value = DateAdd("s", (CLng(H) * 60 + M) * 60 + S, DateSerial(2016, 10, D))
                        .NumberFormat = "dd\/mm\/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
                    End With
                Next S
            Next M
        Next H
    Next D
End Sub
```

Обращаю внимание, что в строке формата используется `dd\/mm\/yyyy`, а не `dd/mm/yyyy` - в случае неэкранированных слешей разделитель будет взят из региональных настроек.

Но желательно:

1. Заранее задать формат для диапазона
2. Как-то более нормально создавать дату - кажется, я перемудрил.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я только добавила `:mm:ss` в формат ячеек)

Comment: @Ksenia, в вопросе было без них, поэтому я подумал, что так и надо.

Answer (score 0):

Установите формат данных для самой ячейки

```
Cells(1, 1).NumberFormat = "dd\/mm\/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
Cells(nRowDate, 1).Date = Date()
```

Comment: Формат неверный, чтобы были именно слеши, надо `"dd\/mm\/yyyy hh"`, иначе он из региональных настроек возьмёт.

Comment: @Qwertiy спасибо за уточнение

Answer (score 0):

Вывод в ячейку с нужным форматированием:

```
Cells(1, 1).Value = Format(Now, "dd/mm/yy yy:mm:ss")
Cells(1, 1).Value = Format(Now, "dd\/mm\/yy yy:mm:ss")
------------------------------------------

' вывести время в формате dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss с заданной периодичностью
Sub DateTime10()
Dim dS As Date, dF As Date
Dim dStep As Double
Dim i As Long, n As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        dS = .Cells(1, 2).Value ' старт
        dF = .Cells(2, 2).Value ' финиш
        dStep = .Cells(3, 2).Value ' шаг, к-во секунд
    End With

    n = Int((dF - dS) * 86400 / dStep) + 1 ' к-во шагов
    dStep = dStep / 86400 ' в секундах (время)
    dS = dS - dStep ' на шаг назад
    ReDim ArrD(1 To n, 1 To 1) ' размерность массива

    For i = 1 To n
        ArrD(i, 1) = dS + dStep * i
    Next i

    With ActiveSheet
        .Columns(4).ClearContents ' чистим перед загрузкой
        .Cells(1, 4).Resize(n, 1).Value = ArrD '  результат на лист
    End With
End Sub
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для отображения даты в другом виде - тот же формат, что и предлагался в коде, но для ячеек:

```
ДД\/ММ\/ГГГГ чч:мм:сс
```